# Application failed to start with Spring config server

Tags: spring-boot

I'm getting started with spring cloud config server and trying to fetch configuration from local git repository but the application can't start

This is the main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The application.properties

```
server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///E:/Projects/Tutorial/git-localconfig-repo
```

The error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method defaultEnvironmentRepository in org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.DefaultRepositoryConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepositoryFactory' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'gitEnvironmentRepositoryFactory' in 'EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.JGitFactoryConfig' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepositoryFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the project working well. For some reason the anti virus was not allowing Intellij to resolve all dependencies. I improved my internet connection and then the IDE brought a pop up with a message `(Windows Defender might be impacting your build and IDE performance. IntelliJ IDEA checked the following directories...` With buttons `Accept automatic configuration` and `Set up manually)` I chose automatic configuration which then after had a successful build.I hope this makes sense. Felt terrible for not trying it out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Add "spring.profiles.active=native" at .properties or .yml file at config server app.

Comment: While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.